# Read variables under return function using variable name

Tags: python, python-2.5

```
>>> class test():
...     def add(self):
...         a = 3+5
...         b = 4+9
...         return a,b
...     
>>> x = test()
>>> x.add()
(8, 13)
>>> z = x.add()
>>> z[0]
8
>>> z[1]
13
```

I looking for way to read individual variable like value of `a` and `b` using variable name not `z[0]` or `z[1]`.

I am also trying to avoid using global variables.

Answer (score 6):

Simply assign like this

```
a, b = x.add()
```

Now, `a` will have 8 and `b` will have 13

Comment: typed almost the same thing, but nevertheless, You rock thefourtheye :)

Comment: @SravanKGhantasala you know you could appreciate Thefoutheye by a simple upvote...

Comment: I don't know if you guys type as fast as I or we just all typed at the same time :) Haha! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

You can used `collections.namedtuple()` for this:

```
from collections import namedtuple


Values = namedtuple("Values", ["a", "b"])


class Test():

    def add(self):
        a = 3 + 5
        b = 4 + 9

        return Values(a=a, b=b)


test = Test()
x = test.add()
print x.a
print x.b
```

**Output:**

```
8
13
```

You could also just return a `dict`. e.g:

```
def add():
    a = 3 + 5
    b = 4 + 9

    return {"a": a, "b": b}
```

Which you would then access via the Python *syntactic sugar* `[key]`, e.g:

```
x["a"]
x["b"]
```

Or you could simply **unpack** the returned *unnamed tuple* like so:

```
a, b = test.add()
```

Answer (score 1):

tuples can be unpacked and stored in variable also

for eg.

```
x,y,z = 2,3,4
def getMyTuple():
   return a,b,c,d

w,x,y,z = getMyTuple()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a kind of this shamanism:

```py
class wrap:
    def __init__(self, **data):
        self.__dict__.update(data)

def named(m):
    def f(self):
        a,b = m(self)
        return wrap(**{'a': a, 'b': b})
    return f

class test:
    @named
    def add(self):
        a = 3+5
        b = 4+9
        return a,b
```

it decorates your method with dictonary (thus, named values) and tranpose them to the properties of the object, i.e. it will work as:

```py
t = test()
x = t.add()

print x.a, x.b
```